# One view for two models with redirect

Tags: django, django-views

I have Django app with the following model:

```
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)
```

This is now using simple generic view:

```
class AuthorDetail(DetailView):
    model = Author
    
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        # some additional context thingies
        return context
```

and with the following URL configuration:

```
path('author/<slug:slug>/', AuthorDetail.as_view(), name='author-detail'),
```

Now I want to introduce simple aliases for authors, so for example instead of `/author/william-shakespeare` I can reach the page also as `/author/ws` or `/author/my-favourite-author`.

I came up with this idea (I know that destination could be key to `Author`, but that (I think) would not change much in the case):

```
class AuthorAlias(models.Model):
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    destination = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

So to achieve the redirect I came up with the following in the view:

```
def get(self, request, **kwargs):
    slug = kwargs['slug']    
    try:
        self.object = self.get_object()
    except Http404:
        self.object = get_object_or_404(AuthorAlias, slug=slug)
        return redirect(reverse('author-detail', args=[self.object.destination]))

    context = self.get_context_data(object=self.object)
    return self.render_to_response(context)
```

Everything seems to be working fine, but I was wondering it there is a better approach and if this approach can cause any issues I'm not seeing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that `destination` does not per se refer to a real author. You can alter this by using a `ForeignKey` instead:

```
class AuthorAlias(models.Model):
    destination = models.ForeignKey('Author', on_delete=models.CASCADE)>
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)
```

In the `Author` class it might be better to implement the [**`get_absolute_url(…)`** method [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/instances/#get-absolute-url) to define a canonical url:

```
from django.urls import reverse

class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('author-detail', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})
```

Now we can implement the `DetailView` with:

```
from django.http import Http404
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, redirect

class AuthorDetail(DetailView):
    model = Author
    
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        # some additional context thingies
        return context

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            self.object = self.get_object()
        except Http404:
            return redirect(get_object_or_404(
                Author,
                authoralias__slug=self.kwargs['slug']
            ))
        context = self.get_context_data(object=self.object)
        return self.render_to_response(context)
```